# Prove that if the partition $\textbf{P}'$ is finer than $\textbf{P}$, then $f$ keeps piecewise constant

Tags: solution-verification, partitions-for-integration

Let $I$ be a bounded interval, let $\textbf{P}$ be a partition of $I$, and let $f:I\to\textbf{R}$ be a function which is piecewise constant with respect to $\textbf{P}$. Let $\textbf{P}'$ be a partition of $I$ which is finer than $\textbf{P}$. Then $f$ is also piecewise constant with respect to $\textbf{P}'$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $\textbf{P} = \{J_{1},J_{2},\ldots,J_{m}\}$ be a partition of $I$. Since $\textbf{P}'$ is finer than $\textbf{P}$, each bounded interval $J_{i}$ can be written as the disjoint union of bounded intervals
\begin{align*}
J_{i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n_{i}}K_{ij}
\end{align*}
where $\textbf{P}' = \{K_{11},\ldots,K_{1n_{1}},\ldots,K_{m1},\ldots,K_{mn_{m}}\}$. Thus, if $x\in K_{ij}$, then $x\in J_{i}$. Consequently, $f|_{K_{ij}} = f|_{J_{i}} = c_{i}$. That's to say, $f$ is also piecewise constant with respect to $\textbf{P}'$, and we are done.

Is there any theoretical flaw in my reasoning? Please let me know if it is the case.

Comment: The intervals $J_i$ must be non-overlapping. You can say $f(x) = c_i$ if $x \in int(J_i)$.  What happens if $x$ is an endpoint of the interval?  If $x \in J_i \cap J_{i+1}$ then how is $f(x)$ defined to be single-valued.  In general, to say $J_i = \bigcup_j K_{ij}$ you need to be clear about the nature (closed or open) of these intervals.  Then you need to be precise about what happens at endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @RRL. But the textbook which I am reading defines partitions as follows: Let $I$ be a bounded interval. A partition of $I$ is a finite set $\textbf{P}$ of bounded intervals contained in $I$, such that every $x$ in $I$ lies in exactly one of the bounded intervals $J$ in $\textbf{P}$. Here, he makes no distinction among $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$ and $[a,b]$. Thus I don't think we need to worry about the endpoints neither about overlapping.

Comment: Using $J_i = [x_{i-1}, x_i)$ probably solves it then.

Answer (score 1):

How about proving it by using just definitions of piecewise constant function and refinement partitions?

Let P and $P'$ be partitions of I such that P' is finer than P.
Suppose $f : I \to R$ is a piecewise constant function with respect to P. So, $\forall$ K $\in$ $P'$ $\exists$ a $J\in P$ such that K$\subseteq$J.

Since f is a constant function on J and K$\subseteq$J, f is also constant on K $\forall$  $K\in P'$. Therefore, f is also piecewise constant with respect to $P'$.